Create a pie chart and change the color of the text on the pie but not the one on the legend
I have created the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}   % omit 'round' option if you prefer square brackets
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Ensure xcolor is loaded for color definitions

% Define custom colors
\definecolor{royalblue}{rgb}{0.25, 0.41, 0.88}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.68, 0.85, 0.90}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[
    color={violet, magenta, pink, blue, cyan, lightblue},
    /tikz/nodes={text=white, font=\bfseries},
    text=legend,
    radius=3, % Adjust the radius for size
    sum=auto, % Automatically calculate the sum
    ]{
    20/Board Director,
    13/Alternate Director,
    11/Board Adviser,
    10/Executive Committee,
    12/Managing Director,
    15/Staff
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Respondents by Category}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

I want the number in the pie to be white and the legend's text to be black.

The answer below uses the wheelchart package, which I wrote.
The values are obtained with the command \WCvarA. This is used in the key wheel data. These are white by specifying the key wheel data style.
The legend is obtained with the keys legend row and legend. Here, the text is obtained with the command \WCvarC.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.68,0.85,0.90}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  data=,
  legend row={\tikz\fill[\WCvarB,draw=black,thick] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WCvarC},
  legend={\node[right] at (3.5,0) {\begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}\WClegend\end{tabular}};},
  pie,
  slices style={\WCvarB,draw=black,thick},
  start angle=0,
  wheel data=\textbf{\WCvarA},
  wheel data style=white
]{%
  20/violet/Board Director,
  13/magenta/Alternate Director,
  11/pink/Board Adviser,
  10/blue/Executive Committee,
  12/cyan/Managing Director,
  15/lightblue/Staff%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: this can also be obtained with the code in the question by removing the part /tikz/nodes={text=white, font=\bfseries}, and replacing it by before number=\color{white}\bfseries,.

Is there no way to do it with \pie?

@ValerioFiccadenti Yes: it is possible to do this with \pie. See the updated answer.
